# Blockchain.info, How to receive new transactions (not websocket)

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info

I'm trying to build safe transaction-confirmation app and need to synchronize new not-processed transactions.

For example I monitor address **A** and have processed last transaction **B**,
how can I ask blockchain "give me all new transactions for address **A**, which occurred after transaction **B**",

or the only way here is to use

> /address/[***]?format=json

url with **offset** and **limit** options ? Thanks

Comment: "give me all new transactions for address A from transaction B" - can you clarify this. By definition a transaction has input and outputs, where outputs are the real indicator, also called UTXOs (unspent transaction outputs). Giving an example with transaction IDs and addresses would certainly get you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain.info's API doesn't operate like a stream like the Twitter feed.  You can't page back and forth through the API like that.

For taking payments, it's best to generate a fresh address to receive the coins than to reuse an address over and over.  It becomes too much trouble to keep track of where/who each coin came from outside of bitcoin (the software running the wallet).  The software does it automatically if you just let it by using a new address for each incoming transaction.  Save the unique receiving address in the db and when it receives funds, you can easily find the order to complete.

Try their [Receive Payments API](https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive).  They automate much of the process and post a callback to you once the funds are received.